# Running several SQL jobs simultaneously under one job

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible in `SQL Server` to run several jobs simultaneously under different sessions under same job.

For example, I have N stored procedures to run. They all have to be run under different sessions and start at the same time. I don't want to create N jobs, I want all of them start at the same time under 1 job.

Comment: Why different sessions?

Comment: @scsimon , I guess you cannot run several jobs simultaneously under 1 session

Comment: Why not in step 1 just put exec proc1; exec proc2; exec proc3; etc...? i'm just a bit confused is all.

Comment: @scsimon, that is the question all about. Because if you do like that, you'll have to wait until proc1 finishes, and then pro2 starts, and then proc2 finishes, and then proc3 starts... I want all of them start at the same time, so that all stuff finishe earlier

Comment: I see what you are getting at now. Well, the best bet is going to be to write a script that creates the jobs for you if you don't want to manually do it. But I'm not sure of another way other than SSIS.

Comment: @scsimon, I just don't want to have too much jobs, that is difficult to manage. I wanted to create one thing that will start running N stored procedures simultaneously

Comment: If you have that many procedures to run you are going to run out of resources anyway so I doubt this is going to have the intended performance improvements you are thinking it might. Also, the pressure on tempdb could become an issue as I am guessing your procedures are not fast or this question wouldn't be asked in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've had one job create and start several other jobs using the sp_add_job command.  If you set the delete level to 3 then the job will then get automatically deleted once it has completed.

The disadvantages are security and monitoring all the jobs.

Comment: This sounds feasible. Let me try. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I don't see any other option than using ssis sql script tasks for different scripts without any link between them and executing them. This will allow to run different SP or sql script to run parallel.Thanks!